# Binance Api - buying and selling functions - python

Tags: binance, binance-api-client

Has anyone made proper working functions for buying and selling a pair like "DOGEUSDT" or any other pair (margin trading),
I have tried my best but I end up with different errors like - Lot size failure, Insufficient funds, or the most commonly known price filter errors of this API

the functions I came up with are below as follows, can someone tell me what am I missing

1. This function is to come up with buy/short quantity and it works pretty fairly

   ```
    def buy_quantity(symbol,asset):
        a = 0
        while a < 3:
            try:
                bal = pd.DataFrame(client.get_margin_account()['userAssets'])
                bal = bal[bal['asset']==asset]
                bal = float(bal['free']) * 0.90
                break
           except:
                print("can't extract asset value..retrying")
                a+=1
        price = float(client.get_recent_trades(symbol=symbol)[0]['price'])    
        stepSize = float(client.get_symbol_info(symbol)['filters'][2]['stepSize'])
        precision = int(round(-math.log(stepSize, 10), 0)) 
        quantity = (bal / price)*0.9995 # Trading fee taken in consideration 
        quantity = round(quantity,precision)
        return quantity
   ```
2. This function is to cover the short, it basically tries to give you the borrowed quantity

   ```
   def sell_quantity1(asset):
        a = 0
        while a < 3:
            try:
                order = pd.DataFrame(client.get_margin_account()['userAssets'])
                order = order[order['asset']==asset]
                order = float(order['borrowed'])
                break
            except:
                print("can't extract borrowed order book...retrying")
                a+=1
        order = round(order,5)
        return order
   ```
3. This function is to sell the long position

   ```
    def sell_quantity2(asset):
        a = 0
        while a < 3:
            try:
                order = pd.DataFrame(client.get_margin_account()['userAssets'])
                order = order[order['asset']==asset]
                order = float(order['free'])
                break
            except:
                print("can't extract order book...retrying")
                a+=1
        order = round(order,5)
        return order
   ```

I think the functions 2 & 3 should work properly like the function 1 but they don't, some or the other error pops out
Lot size failure, Insufficient funds, or something else, what am I missing here can someone please help me I am struggling for a couple of days

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
def order(side, quoteOrderQty, symbol, order_type=ORDER_TYPE_MARKET):
    try:
        order = client.create_order(symbol=symbol, side=side, type=order_type, quoteOrderQty=quoteOrderQty)
        print(order)
    except Exception as e:
        print("exception - {}".format(e))
```